# pymongo's find_one method return None but document exists in DB

Tags: python, multithreading, mongodb

I struggle with problem that relates to pymongo and threads.
I've got a python application which use threads. This app does queries thru pymongo, like `db.collection.find_one({'_id': obj_id})`. But very often, these queries return None, however object with this id exists in DB. I can't reproduce this behavior on my local machine, I don't know why. This happens only in production.

I read this [article](https://emptysqua.re/blog/requests-in-python-and-mongodb/), which talks about pymongo, sockets and threads. But this article describes old approach, that used to in older version of pymongo. Also, I found this similar [issue](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/860)

I use one instance of connection in all threads `pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27100/my_db').get_default_database()`. I thought that None maybe comes as reponse for another thread because pymongo uses pool of sockets.

For example: thread_1 does query and get to sleep. After this query socket back to pymongo pool. thread_2 wake up and does query but pymongo gets socket that was used by thread_1 and thread_2 gets foreign response.

It's only a idea. I'm not sure that it's true.

Which problem can I have?

```
PS: I use pymongo==3.3.0 and MongoDB 3.2.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't get a reason of the problem. I used workaround. I loaded all necessary documents to memory and worked with its.